# gridview from 2 tables visual studio 2005

Tags: asp.net, gridview

What is the efficient way to make a gridview from 2 tables (one of them is using the primary key of the other as a foreign key) using visual studio 2005?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nested gridview (or datalist/repeater) is what you need. You need to create `TemplateField` in parent GridView to add another Gridview in it. Handle the `RowDataBound` event of parent gridview to bind its child elements/controls.

PS: You may read MSDN pages/tutorial about GridView and its events.

MSDN Link  : [Walkthrough: Creating a Nested GridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992038%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks AVD, actually I read them but some functions are applied only to visual studio 2008..

Comment: It doesn't matter whether a GridView of 2.0 or 3.5 framework version.

Comment: I referred to this link http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-4 but when I try to use asp:EntityDataSourc tag I got error message said that (Element 'EntityDataSource' is not a known element.)

Comment: Don't use EntityDataSource. Lookup how to use a SqlDataSource. That's an easy one.